# Symfony Doctrine fails to create foreign key

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, foreign-keys

Fields in table `Ordertaxi`:

```
@ORM\Column(name="custom_id", type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
private $customId;

// new "column", which i want to add
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CustomOrder")
private $custom;
```

Field in table `CustomOrder`:

```
@ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
@ORM\Id
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
private $id;
```

---

Executing:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Getting:

```
ALTER TABLE Ordertaxi ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D345B7FB614A603A FOREIGN KEY (custom_id) REFERENCES CustomOrder (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_D345B7FB614A603A ON Ordertaxi (custom_id)
```

Executing:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Getting:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                                                                       
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE Ordertaxi ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D345B7FB614A603A FOREIGN KEY (custom_id) REFERENCES CustomOrder (id  
  )':                                                                                                                                                 
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'aerotaxi.#sql-3b8a_4c' (errno: 150)
```

Why does this query lead to an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to Ordertaxi this code

```
@JoinColumn(name="customOrder_id", referencedColumnName="id")
```